# Solve the pde : $x^2(y-z)\,\partial_x(z)+y^2(z-x)\,\partial_y(z)=z^2(x-y)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have tried solving it using lagrange auxiliary equations. I found one solution as $xyz=c$, but I am unable to find another solution.

Comment: How is this a PDE? What is $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Hi vivek, as I commented on your previous question, it is better to write differential operators explicitly as such if you want people to understand your question.

Comment: My mistake! P= partial differentiation of z wrt x AND q= partial differentiation of z wrt y

Comment: My mistake! P= partial differentiation of z wrt x AND q= partial differentiation of z wrt y

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you call this PDE, but you can rewrite equation as
$${px^2+z^2 \over x-z} = {qy^2+z^2 \over y-z}$$
(unless $x=z$ or $y=z$ which gives additional solutions $x=y=z$, $x=\pm \sqrt{-q \over p+1}y=z$ and $y=\pm \sqrt{-p \over q+1}x=z$)

From ${px^2+z^2 \over x-z}=c$ we have $x(c,z)$ and likewise $y(c,z)$ (for $c$ not between $2z(p \pm \sqrt{p^2+p})$ and not between $2z(q \pm \sqrt{q^2+q})$). There can be some more elegant parametrization, but this does describe your solution.

Comment: This is not the solution which I want..anyways thanks...it is a non linear pde where p=dz/dx and q=dz/dy.can't we solve this using lagrange auxiliary equations?

Comment: @vivek Oh, sorry. Then use $u(x,y)={z(x,y) \over xy}$, you'll arrive to $u_x'{x^3 \over x^2-1} = u_y'{y^3 \over y^2-1}$ and $u(x,y)=f(ln(xy)+{1 \over 2x^2}+{1 \over 2y^2})$. (Unless I made a mistake somewhere in calculations)